# Node js defining response payload structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, model

I am having a data coming from elastic search with hits object through node server  .  I want to send back to the user by transforming it into a payload structure object . For example ,

````
{
"title":"test",
"count":36
"description":"something for test"
},
{...}
]```

Then from this array I want only title to be sent to user . How can I transform in node js as an object by defining a model

Transform Structure : 

    ```{ "pageNo":1, 
       "payload":
        [ 
        {"title":"test"}
          ,{...},
           {...} 
] }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with array so you need to iterate over it. Best approach in that case is to use **map** method:

```js
const array = [
  {
    "title":"test",
    "count":36,
    "description":"something for test",
  },
];

const responseItems = array.map(item => {
  return { title: item.title };
});

const response = {
  payload: responseItems,
  // other fields...
};
```